# Transformar colunas em linhas em um dataframe

Tags: python, data.frame, pandas

Tenho um *dataframe* com as colunas:

```
LUC
Contrato
Fantasia
Ano
Mes
01
02
03
05
...
30
Tatividade
```

Preciso transformar essas colunas com os dias do mes em linhas. Em cada coluna tem o valor vendido naquele dia pela loja. Teria que ficar assim:

```
LUC
Contrato
Fantasia
Ano 
mes
dia
valor
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei o código:

```
vendas = pd.melt(vendas.reset_index(), id_vars=['LUC', 'Contrato','Fantasia','ano','mes','Tatividade'], 
var_name='dia', value_name='valor')
```

As colunas foram criadas, mas o valores ficaram incorretos. Na coluna dia ficou o valor index e na coluna valor ficou uma sequência númerica.

Answer (score 2):

Tentou transpor o dataframe?

Ele faz a inversão entre linhas e colunas.

```
pd = pd.T
```

Answer (score 0):

Cara, já tentou separar esta operação `reset_index()`?

Testa essa solução:

```
vendas = pd.melt(vendas, 
                 id_vars=['LUC','Contrato','Fantasia','ano','mes','Tatividade'], 
                 var_name='dia', 
                 value_name='valor')
vendas.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```